how to cancel previous operation if the next operation returns an error
I'm developing a telegram bot which stores users' reminders.
The bot creates a scheduled job using package github.com/go-co-op/gocron. To create a scheduled job it saves in DB information about it and creates a scheduled job in gocron. But what if gocron returnes an error? the information will remain in the database, but it will not correspond to reality.
Let me show you an example of this situation:
func (n *ReminderService) SaveAndStartReminder(ctx context.Context, userID int64, loc *time.Location, task gocron.Task) (gocron.NewJob, error) {
    // saving in DB
    err := n.Save(ctx, userID)
    if err != nil {
        return gocron.NewJob{}, err
    }

    // saving in gocron
    nextRun, err := n.CreateReminder(ctx, loc, task, r)
    if err != nil {
        return gocron.NewJob{}, err
    }

    return nextRun, nil
}

so my question is: how to cancel previous operation if the next operation returns an error? how to cancel n.Save(ctx, userID) if the n.CreateReminder(ctx, loc, task, r) returns an error?

What about flipping the operation? I mean: first create the crob job then store in the db and in case of db error cancel the job from the scheduler scheduler.RemoveJob(nextRun.ID())

Either what @Matteo said (which is the order in which I'd do things to being with), or, if the order of operations is somehow set in stone: wrap the DB insert in a transaction, and roll the transaction back if you couldn't create the cron job. Still, I'd prioritise creating the cornjob first, because that way you should be able to add the PID to the record.
